# Update client data on database update

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm building my first SaaS B2C application using ReactJS + Relay + GraphQL + MongoDb. As an example, the application would have the following objects:

- User
- Customer
- StockItem
- StockLevel
- PriceList
- Sales
- Returns

For each object I can see its listing (ex: List of items on stock - StockItem List), as well details of an object. An object can be created, edited or deleted (CRUD).

Using REST I would build for each object a data fetcher. So once the user goes to list Sales, i.e., the client would go to the server and fetch all available Sales. If the user clicks to detail it, a new REST call would be done to get this specific Sales details, and so on.

Using GraphQL I understood that I should create a big `viewer` query briging all those objects and fields to the application, and use fragments to access them for each object.

Doing so, I can't understand what will happen if another user changes some object, as all data is going to be loaded at once in the beginning of the application. Will Relay reload the fragment once a new screen is opened working in the same way it is done using REST? Should I build an update mechanism ? If so, what are the ways to go.

Remember I have 40+ different objects

Or maybe I need to build one query for each object the same way I do using REST?

Comment: I did not work with GraphQL or Relay before so I don't know about them but I thing you need to figure out some sort of Pub/Sub logic to notify user that the data is changed. MongoDb Oplog records every operation that made to the db. You can listen for those operations and if the related data is changed by some other user you can refresh the data on the other users browser. I believe Meteor uses similar type of approach.

Comment: Is there a straightfoward way to do it, otherwise it will be crazy for 40+ objects I have currently.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to build one query for each object.

The queries are called with `<QueryRenderer />` with Relay.
You will have one `<QueryRenderer />` associated with a query each time you want to query something in a batch.

For example, let's imagine 2 pages: `/users` and `/sales`, which are both lists.

`/users` can render, somewhere:

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={...}
  query={graphql`
    query UsersPageQuery {
      users(first: 10) {
        edges { node {
          ...UsersPage_user
        }}
      }
    }
  `
  // ... others props
/>
```

And `/sales` can render, somewhere:

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={...}
  query={graphql`
    query SalesPageQuery {
      sales(first: 10) {
        edges { node {
          ...SalesPage_sale
        }}
      }
    }
  `
  // ... others props
/>
```

**Do not** load all the data at once.
A good idea would be to have one `<QueryRenderer />` per view, like a list, or a item details view. Same splitting as in REST ;)

Comment: As an example, I would need a `<QueryRenderer />` for `Users` (return list of all users with major properties - ex: name, email, phone), a `<QueryRenderer />` for `User(id)` (a certain user passing its id and returning all of its details: name, email, phone, address, city, zip, social security, last shopping, etc.). If I have 40 objects I will have around 80 queries (one for the object listing and one for object details). Is that the idea ? I was worried to use too much queries and was looking to find a way to reduce them....